# How to get row number and make it another column in DataFrames in Julia?

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I need to inner-join 2 dataframes: routes and sources. Joining should be on `routes.source`=`sources.row number`. And I don't see how to do it (in Python/Pandas you'd just do `right_index=True`). I've checked the [DataFrames.jl doc](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.rownumber), and can't see how to join on row number. Nor I could convert row number into another column.

Routes:

[image: Routes, source number in column "source"]

Sources:

[image: Sources, source number is row number]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataFrame` does not have a row index, unlike e.g. a pandas DataFrame.

If you want to join on the row number, you can just create it as a column:

```
sources.row_num = 1:nrow(sources)
```

and then

```
innerjoin(routes, sources, on = :source => :row_num)
```

to perform an inner join where the `source` column of `routes` and the `row_num` column of `sources` are used to perform the join.